# Connection could not be established with [ #0]

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm working with symfony 2 framework, trying to send mail using swiftmailer .
I'm getting the error : Connection could not be established with "myhost" [ #0]

My conf.yml :

```
   swiftmailer:
      transport:  smtp
      encryption: ssl
      auth_mode:  login
      port:       587
      host:       myHostWebMail eg: mail.company.fr
      username:   xx@company.fr
      password:   mypassword
      delivery_address:   EmailAdress
      disable_delivery:   false
```

When i changed the port to 26, i get this error :

```
    Connection could not be established with host mail.company.fr [No 
    connection could be established because the target computer expressly refused.#10061]
```

From where is the problem ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was actually a line missing :

```
   spool: {type: memory }
```